# Facebook Page Feed Targeting Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We have been able to create feed posts on a Facebook page using the Graph API. We have multiple posts and each posts is targeted at a different region and different locale.

The problem is that we are able to see the multiple posts when we view the pages as a non-admin user.

The posts would have something like:

Visible to: Location - Living In: Canada: Ontario,
Language: English(US) or English (UK)
News Feed Audience: Location - Living In: Canada: Ontario,
Language: English(US) or English (UK)

We are using v2.8 of the GraphApi.